# How to accomplish the testcafe test structure like mocha

Tags: testing, automated-tests, mocha.js, e2e-testing, testcafe

Testcafe provides fixtures and tests to organize the tests. How can I use fixture and test to accomplish the test structure like below mocha structure

Here is the example test structure in mocha

```
describe('test', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    ....
  }

  describe('test suite 1', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      ...
    }

    it('test1', () => {
      ...
    }

    it('test2', () => {
      ...
    }
  }

  describe('test suite 2', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      ...
    }

    it('test3', () => {
      ...
    }

    it('test4', () => {
      ...
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

At present, TestCafe doesn't allow creating nested tests, but we may implement this feature in the future. I suggest you track the https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/792 issue in the TestCafe repository to be informed about our progress in this regard.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I will keep an eye on the this ticket. 
https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/792